# Subir archivos nodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs

quiesiera saber mi ayudar por favor en lo siguiente: tengo una api que está desarrollada en nodejs con restify y mysql, necesito en un endpoint en donde se ingresan varios campos de un formulario, insertar además una imagen y que la ruta de esta quede registrada en un campo de la BD, cómo es posible realizar esto?, he probado con multer pero lamentablemente no he logrdo resultados, les dejo el codigo que actualmente estoy utilizando.

Hago las pruebas a través de postman [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] pero lamentablemente no me arroja ningún error, ningún mensaje relacionado a la carga del archivo, sólo me figura un error debido que los campos que acompañan este archivo van vacíos (lo tengo así para dedicarme por ahora solamente a cargar el archivo)

server.js

```
        // Versión 1.0.0
    require('dotenv').config({ path: 'env.env' });

    const corsMiddleware = require('restify-cors-middleware')

    const moment = require('moment');

    // const multer = require('multer');
    // const path = require('path');


    const joi = require('joi');

    const validator = require('./common/validator');
    const handler = require('./common/errorHandler');

    const API_MIN_VERSION = '1.0.0';
    const API_CURRENT_VERSION = process.env.APPLICATION_ENV;

    const restify = require('restify');
    const versioning = require('restify-url-semver');

    const server = restify.createServer({
      name : `Comercio Adherido Api v:${API_CURRENT_VERSION}`,
      acceptable: 'application/json',
      versions: [API_MIN_VERSION, API_CURRENT_VERSION],
      version: API_CURRENT_VERSION,
      rejectUnauthorized: true,
      ignoreTrailingSlash: true,
      handleUncaughtExceptions: true,
      formatters: { 'application/json': require('./common/jsend') }
    });

    server.pre(restify.pre.sanitizePath());
    server.pre(versioning({ prefix: '/' }));

    server.use(restify.plugins.gzipResponse());
    server.use(restify.plugins.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
    server.use(restify.plugins.queryParser({ mapParams: true }));
    server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser({ mapParams: true }));
    server.use(restify.plugins.urlEncodedBodyParser({ mapParams : true }));
    server.use(restify.plugins.throttle({
      burst: 100,
      rate: 50,
      ip: true
    }));


    // Setup validators
    server.use(validator.paramValidation(joi));
    handler.register(server);

    // Setup route Handling
    const comercioAdheridoRouters = require('./routers/v1/comercio-adherido-routers');
    comercioAdheridoRouters.register(server);



    const cors = corsMiddleware({
      preflightMaxAge: 5,
      origins: ['http://localhost:3000'],
      allowHeaders: ['Authorization'],
      allowMethods: ['*'],
      exposeHeaders: ['API-Token-Expiry']
    });

    server.pre(cors.preflight);
    server.use(cors.actual);

    const port = process.env.API_PORT || 3001;

    const ipaddress = process.env.IP;


    server.listen(process.env.PORT || port, ipaddress, function () {
      console.log('Server %s listening at %s', server.name, server.url)

    })
```

routers.js

```
server.post({path: '/comercioAdherido/',version: '1.0.0'}, 
upload.single('detalle_comercio_adherido'),methods.insertComAdh)
```

methods.js

```
            let _insert = async function (req, res, next){
            try{
            
                const { params } = req;
                let result = await comAdhServices.insertComAdh(params);

                if(result === null){
                    res.json(httpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
                    res.end();
                    return;
                }
                res.json(httpStatus.CREATED, result[0]);
                res.end();
                
            }catch(err){
                res.send(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, JSON.stringify({Error: httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, Message: constants.Error.INTERNALERROR}) );
            }
        };
```

Comment: no lo has logrado? por favor explica un poco más, tienes un error?, no se te sube la imagen?, no entiendes la documentación?

Comment: oka, edito mi pregunta